# How to prevent popup window when opening a new tab

Tags: javascript, popupwindow

I use the `window.open(url, '_blank');` in order to open new tab but sometime the popup windows appear. How can I prevent this?

Thank

Comment: create an anchor tag and to that give target as "_blank" it will open the url in a new tab instead of a window

Comment: @Manish this is not necessary. Please open the link provided by Aurel.